# Lodash Filter sigue buscando a pesar que ya encontró el destino

Tags: javascript, firebase, filtro

me encontré con un nuevo problema, resulta que estoy usando Lodash, y al momento de buscar un item, en este caso un "key" que me retorna Firebase, lo encuentra, pero después de eso, sigue su función, y me da resultado que no espero, acá una muestra de mi código, de antemano, muchas gracias.

Cuando encuentra el item que ocupo, sigue su búsqueda y me empieza a lanzar el mensaje de "error, parece que no tienes datos para mostrar"

```
encontrado = _.filter(childDataItem, function(item) {
return item.key === monthName;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución, en vez de utilizar la función "filter", utilicé "findIndex", cerraré la pregunta, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: La pregunta no se cierra, califica tu respuesta y con eso basta

Answer (score 0):

Dos cosillas Ricardo:

Creo que no tienes muy claro el concepto de filter. Por lo que entiendo en tu pregunta, crees que filter recorre el array y cuando encuentra uno que cumpla la condición este rompe la función y devuelve el item, pero no es así la función filter devuelve TODOS los elementos que en el retorno de la función sera verdadero. Es decir si todas las ejecuciones de la función devuelven verdadero devolvera todos los elementos y viceversa.

Por otro lado esa comparación triple ( return item.key === monthName;) no tiene muy buena pinta... Prueba con una comparación simple (==) si no buscas comparar dos elementos de distintos tipos, como un int contra un string o algo así

Saludos!!

Comment: Hola Raúl, gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo he intentado así (==) y pues, da el mismo error, como dices, no tengo muy claro el concepto de filter, pero siempre lo he utilizado, hasta para hacer procesos de login, ¿Tienes algún mejor método para una solución? ¡Mil gracias!

Comment: No, yo tambien uso filter solo que si te salen varios resultados, lo mejor es que generes una condición mejor que separe los conjuntos y si no importa que elemento sea el que devuelva, coje el primer elemento del array